# Is it possible to override a set DependencyProperty of a nested Control with a XAML-Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.6.1

Lets assume there is a `Control` with a default `Style` which i can only base-on or override. In this `Style` there is a `ControlTemplate` which has another `Control` and sets the `Value` of a `DependencyProperty` directly.

Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ParentControl}" x:Key="Test">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ParentControl}">
                <ChildControl Property="Value" ... />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now i want to change the `Value` of the `Property` in the `ChildControl` without access/changing the default `Style`.

If i'm not mistaken, the `Foreground` of the `ChildControl` can't be overridden with a simple `Style-Setter` due the [Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

```
<!-- Doesen't Work -->
<Style TargetType="{x:type ChildControl}">
    <Setter Property="Property" Value="Value"/>
</Style>
```

But according to the same Source it would be possible to override it with an `Animation` (if the Animation lasts forever).

Right there, i'm stuck. More precisely: I can't override the `IsDirectionReversed` `Property` of the vertical `ScrollBar`-`Track` in a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="300" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Track}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SetValue">
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Track.IsDirectionReversed)">
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="24:00:00">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="00:00:00"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SetValue"/>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <Rectangle Height="800"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Is there something wrong with the `Trigger`/`Animation`? Or does the Behaviour of the `Track`-`Control` not change when the `IsDirectionReversed`-`Property` is set via `Animation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define an implicit `ScrollBar` style and put the `Track` style inside the `Resources` dictionary of this one. Then your style should get applied to the `Track` element:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="300" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Track}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SetValue">
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Track.IsDirectionReversed)">
                                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="24:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="00:00:00"/>
                                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SetValue"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <Rectangle Height="800" Fill="Red"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was the Style not applied because the default `ScrollViewer` is built upon a `ControlTemplate` and not a `Style`? Or Why solved the implicit `Style` the problem?